# Accessing request object in serializeUser function in passport.js

Tags: node.js, passport.js

I am writing simple app using node.js and passport.js for auth.

Can I get access to the request object in serializeUser?

Comment: I wanted to ask this question. [It seems there already is a way to do this now](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/issues/111) but unfortunately I'm not that well versed with passport to understand how it actually works. Could someone please answer this explain how the `req` is accessed inside `passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done)`?

Answer (score 10):

It's actually pretty simple: `req` is added as the first parameter

```
passport.deserializeUser(function(req, id, done) {...
```

https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/issues/111

If you do `req.res.render('whatever'` it works.

Answer (score 3):

I think yttrium and laggingreflex questions are slightly different:

To answer yttrium:

To access the request object you have to do it inside an express middleware that will deal with authorization of your resource.

```
function authMethod(req, res, next) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) 
    { 
        console.log(req.user);
        return next(); 
    }
    res.status(401).send({user:undefined});
}
app.get('/',authMethod,function(req,response)
{
     res.status(200).send("OK");
}
```

If you have done the configuration right, Passaport will make modifications to your request object, so you can access the user information with `req.user`. You also have a method, `req.isAuthenticated()`, to check if the third-party auth was succeeded.

To answer laggingreflex:

You can't access the request object inside `passport.deserializeUser` and `passport.serializeUser` because those methods are made to deal with the serialization of the user information inside a session (Look at the [github](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport#sessions) explanation). Those methods receive an object and a function as parameters. On `serializeUser` the first parameter is an object with user information that you will serialize and pass to the `done`function (callback). On `deserializeUser` the first parameter is an object that was serialized that you have to do the reverse operation.